# Cloud Storage vs. Datastore latency

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I have a simple data file I want to store. I don't need any indexes or queries performed on it, so I can put it in Cloud Storage. BUT, the latency of fetching the file is very important. What is the latency I can expect when fetching a file from Cloud Storage vs. the latency in fetching an entity from the Datastore?

I could not find a good reference for this issue...

Comment: try it out. Not that hard to make a little test app. Post results here to discuss it. I think its interesting

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't expect a specific latency as it'll vary depending on a large number of things. If the file is that important, then just package it with the files when distributing the program if that's possible.

Comment: The large number of things that determine the latency are exactly the things I'm asking about

Answer (score 1):

If this is a file that fits within the limits of Datastore entity (1 MB size). Then storing the file there makes sense.

I have seen lower latency on Datastore retrieval than GCS (again depends highly on the size of the object).

Another advantage using Datastore would be with is using the NDB Python interface as it will transparently cache the entity to memcache.

Comment: If you care about latency, read the file once on instance start (warmup requests) and cache it in in-instance cache.

Comment: Can you elaborate how much lower latency have you found the datastore to be? I would like to see actual numbers to help me decide...